# matlab serial communication

Tags: matlab, serial-port

```
SerPIC = serial('COM10'); 
set(SerPIC,'BaudRate', 115200, 'DataBits', 8, 'Parity', 'none','StopBits', 1, 'FlowControl', 'software');
fopen(SerPIC); %--open the serial port to the PIC
fprintf(SerPIC, '%s', 'b'); 
fid = fopen('D:\pipt1.abs');
tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
  fprintf(SerPIC, '%s',tline )
    tline = fgets(fid);
end
fclose(fid); 
fclose(SerPIC) %--close the serial port when done
delete(SerPIC)
clear SerPIC
```

I am using Tms570ls20216 usb. In the board i have bootloader in it. When i send a b to the board it'll flash the board after taking the abs file. Its working properly in hyperterminal but while running in matlab its not flashing. I am new to matlab. Is there anything wrong in my code. I dont know whether this is a proper place to ask the question. Sorry if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to send a line-feed at the end of your `b` command?  Like this:

```
fprintf(SerPIC, 'b\n');  %add line feed, no need for %s from the original code
```